# Chrome not loading all webpack JS source files, but Firefox + Chrome Incognito does

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, vue.js, webpack

We've run into a recent deployment issue with our Vue.js app served via Heroku.

The high-level problem is that, when we redeploy to our Dev environment, the app only loads in Chrome Incognito mode or in Firefox.

The app does **not** load in normal Chrome - instead it returns a blank white page.

We're concerned that when we promote from Dev -> Staging -> Prod, users will also experience this caching issue and the app will not load for them.

One thing we noticed is that a file which is loaded in incognito mode, `login.js`, is not being loaded in non-incognito.

.

*Non-incognito mode*

[image: Non-incognito mode]

*Non-incognito source files*

[image]

*(Here we can see that `login.js`, as well as an `img` folder, fails to load)*

.

*Incognito mode*

[image: Incognito mode]

*Incognito source files*

[image]

Another thing we noticed is that `bootstrap` seems to be initiating this call in incognito mode, but we don't see this request in non-incognito. Perhaps bootstrap is failing to load?

We also see this in the console:

[image: Console]

Therefore it seems like something is not being loaded, or is being cached (and therefore the newest/correct version is not loaded).

We experience this problem even if we activate "Disable cache" in Chrome Dev Tools in non-incognito mode.

We're not sure if this is a caching issue, or a webpack issue, or maybe just a Chrome issue. Does anyone know why these source files may be failing to load in non-cognito mode?

.

*Edit*: I also disabled all Chrome Extensions in non-incognito mode to no avail. Another developer on our team confirmed the issue on his end, however, a second developer does not have the issue at all in Chrome.

To replicate the issue, you can't just visit the website *once*. In fact, you need to visit it once, then a new version must deploy, and then upon reloading the page, it will fail to load.

.

*Edit 2*: One more thing I noticed is that the correct version incognito loads TWO OF EACH `login.js` and `login.css`. The non-incognito version fails to call the second versions. I wonder if there is a name conflict somehow being cached?

[image]

Comment: If you browser is caching the HTML, and the fingerprint on the js file changes whenever the js changes your browser will not see the changes. View source on the page and be sure the script tags and image tags are what you expect. On the network tab select the `all` sub-tab and check if your html document is being loaded from disk cache. Check the response headers on html page response - the Cache-Control header  should be configured so your browser doesn't cache the page. Something like `Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate`

Comment: Thanks @ScottJacobsen. I applied django's `never_cache` function, and now this is returned in the Response Headers: `Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate`. However, the page still does not load. (This would be consistent with the page not loading when we "Disabled cache" in Dev Tools.) The `index.html` does not seem to be being loaded by cache. Also, all the `.js` and `.css` files match those by filename/content as those in incognito (I diff'd them). So I am not sure any of these approaches worked unfortunately.

Comment: The problem seemed to go away when I went to `Application`->`Clear storage`. However, I am not sure if I can use webpack or something to force a clear storage, as opposed to simply clearing a cache for the user. Again, this doesn't seem like a cache issue, but rather a storage one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe we figured out the answer.

`Clear storage` affects 3 things.

1. Service workers
2. Storage
3. Cache

We were pretty sure it's not a cache issue because we added `Content: no-cache` and `Disable cache` in Chrome Dev Tools. Additionally, we don't use any Service workers for the app.

We switched from using `localStorage` (persistent) in our application code to using `sessionStorage` (ephemeral).

This seemed to solve the issue.